# Круглый ProgressBar с 4 цветами (неплавный градиент)

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, градиент

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Update: залил новый скриншот, от 0 до 165 у нас круг закрашен, прогресс равен ~ 45%, остальная часть тусклыми цветами

Есть ли возможность сделать progressbar с 4 цветами? По сути это градиент, но вот только у тэга gradient нет параметров, позволяющих сделать строго разграниченные цвета (знаю, что в api 24 такое вроде можно сделать, но мне нужно с api 15 и выше). Для прогресса использую shape ring:

```
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="130"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="130">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="14.0"
            android:useLevel="true"/>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: _"Есть ли возможность сделать progressbar с 4 цветами?"_ - Конечно есть. В мире программирования вы сами определяете границы реальности. Вы сами творите эту реальность, ведь вы создатель. _"По сути это градиент"_ - Это и близко не градиент _"вот только у тэга gradient нет параметров, позволяющих сделать строго разграниченные цвета"_ - Тогда такой градиент перестанет быть градиентом. Ибо одно из определений градиента в том, что у него линейные изменения, а тебе нужны дискретные значения.

Comment: _"Для прогресса использую shape ring"_ - А я сегодня на завтрак покушал макароны со слегка подгоревшим луком в качестве зажарки и с сайрой, которая осталась со вчерашнего дня. Мне не понравилось, но это то, что у меня было. _"Заранее спасибо."_ - На здоровье! _"https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH4Q2.jpg"_  - А это вообще называется pie chart и ни к прогресс-барам, ни к градиентам отношения не имеет. Хоть немного подучите терминологию и тогда мир погромирования станет проще и интереснее.

Comment: проще вам использовать что то готовое для вывода графиков (а это круговая диаграма, а никакой не прогресс-бар), например либу [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). На гитхабе можно и попроще найти конечно

Answer (score 1):

Путаетесь в терминологии - это раздражает многих, но не меня :-)
(Просьбы о не плавном градиенте равнозначны мольбам о квадрате но без углов)

Видимо вам нужны не градиенты а круговые диаграммы ну а дальше берите любую за основу и изменяйте в нужном вам направлении; присмотритесь например к [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart), как вам верно подсказал [@pavlofff](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177345/pavlofff) в комментарии.